# Open single pop up from two different buttons

Tags: asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I have two different buttons viz save and update. I want to open single pop-up window for both buttons, then how can I do so.? More over if pop-up is open on save buttons click then when ever it is closed, it should directed to OnClick_save() button event and if it is open from update buttons, on pop-up colse, it should directed to OnClick_Update() buttons click event.

How can I do so??
This is my code

```
<tr>
<td>
<table id="tblButton" runat="server">
   <tr>
       <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" Visible="false"  />
      &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" Visible="false" />&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" Visible="false" />
      &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnTargetButton" runat="server" Text="PopUpTarget" Visible="false" />
       </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderSave" runat="server"    TargetControlID="btnTargetButton" PopupControlID="passwordPopUp" DropShadow="true"   PopupDragHandleControlID="header" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" BehaviorID="ModalPopupExtenderSave" />

</table>
<asp:Panel ID="passwordPopUp" runat="server" Style="display: none; padding: 10px;
border: 1px; border-style: solid;" BackColor="#91C83B" Width="300px"   HorizontalAlign="Center"
BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="5px">
<table class="TABLE100">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <h3 style="text-align: center;" id="header">
                Confirm Password</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td width="50px">
            <asp:Label ID="lblPasswrd" runat="server" Text="Password" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" SkinID="TextBoxLong"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" Width="70px" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Some how I have solved the problem up to certain extent.
Now the problem is three different buttons viz. Insert, Update and delete buttons are responsible for opening pop-up window which in turn opens an ASP:panel the panel contains submit button. So on submit button, can I know which button was responsible for opening a panel.???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a hidden button as modal popup's **Okbutton** and call then button **OnClick** from code. from both Save and Updated buttons.

Comment: as your `btnTargetButton` is hidden
lets say in your **btnSubmit_Click** you do all the logic and when you need to call the MPE(Modal Popup Extender) you just call `btnTargetButton_Click` and in that button's **Click** handler you call MPE like `MPE.show()` and then after doing all you intended work you write `MPE.hide()` and close Modal Popup.

Comment: ..But on the submit event I want to do insert,update and delete. So before each operation I need to open pop-up to enter password. If password is correct then and only then the operation should be done. And how to know which operation is to do at particular moment.?? Please provide code if possible...

Comment: `btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //some code 
   ........
   ........
   //befor insert

  //call popup like
   popup.show();
}


//In your popup you enter login/password and press submit

btnSubmit_Click(...)
{
   if(validUser)
      insert();
      :
      :
      //after doing intended opration just call
      popup.hide();
}`

Same can be achieved for delete, update
hope it helps...:)

Comment: ..Pop-up will be called 3 times for each insert,update and delete. After validating user I need to click btnSubmit. So how to know if the button btnSubmit is clicked for insert, update or delete??  Here single button is responsible for all three operation.

Comment: use a **field** to hold the value/name of a button that called this popup then use this field in modal popup like

`if(field == "insert")
    insertData();

 else if(field == "delete")
    deleteData();

 else if(field == "Update")
    UpdateData();
`
_in field you will store the name of operation you wish to do_
**like**
on btnInsert(.....)
`field = "insert;"`

Answer (score 0):

add server side event handlers for each button click. use jquery to show popup for each button, that would be `$('#button1').click` and `$('#button2').click` from jquery.